# ffmpeg command into batch command

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, script

I was trying to get an command I use and have to apply to batch list of files instead of doing it for each file.

Command I use for ffmpeg (has to keep `-i` and `-c`) - `ffmpeg -i in.ts -c copy out.mp4`

How can I turn that command into doing it for all files in a folder and not change manually the actual file name into "in.ts" and spit it out in it's original filename?

Attempts at Solution:
Tried wildcard but it failed. Also tried this `for %%A IN (*.ts) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c "%%A.mp4"`

Ideally I want to turn it into a .bat and just run it within a dir of choice.

Comment: in what way is it failing, show the error or issue you have or see with your command.. also I suggest you do `do echo ffmpeg`  not `do ffmpeg`  so that you see what  gets outputted.. Then when it's right for you, remove the echo.

Comment: also to not get a situation where you have an output file that is like `blah.txt.mp4` you ca ndo your command with a `~n` on the output filename like `C:\blah>for %A IN (*.mp4) DO @echo ffmpeg -i "%A" -c "%~nA.mp4"` See the end of `for /?` for mention of `~n`

Comment: I'm not the best with scripting but error is trailing options were found on the commandline.

Comment: you should include the command and the error message you get, in your question. copy paste the command and the error

Comment: the error you mention is an ffmpeg related error , so maybe you get it even without the for statement? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57442653/ffmpeg-trailing-options-were-found-on-the-commandline

Comment: with ffmpeg, and `-c`,  isn't it meant to be `-c copy` not just -c. Try `-c copy`.